# VoidCallback, Function(x), Valuechanged<T>, Valuesetter<T> which one for callbacks ? (Flutter/Dart)

Tags: flutter, dart, callback

I pretty much know that those concepts are used to call a function in another widget or to notify parent that a value changed. I try to understand which one to use depending on the case :

- VoidCallback
- Function(x) (widget field)
- ValueChanged
- ValueSetter

For instance, I already used ValueChanged like I use Voidcallback

Answer (score -1):

First you pick what *your* function needs as input and gives as output (when it's a callback, it's probably about what you can *give* as input and *need* as output).

And then you pick the one that fits that signature.

You shouldn't pick one and make your functionality fit it. It's tools. Use them if needed, feel free to use different one's if not.

Comment: I think, what he is expecting as answer is to tell him what each one is for. This is expecially when he wants to customize the callback himself.

Answer (score -1):

You'd better use VoidCallback when you're passing no value as parameter inside the paranthesis;

Use ValueChanged for passing values